# Reuse ngClass directive in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to validate a form and there is just way too much logic in the html page. I am already using ngMessages because it's quite hopeless without it.

I am doing the object variant of ng-class like this

```
ng-class="{ 'has-error' : registerForm.username.$invalid && registerForm.username.$touched, 'has-success' : registerForm.username.$valid && registerForm.username.$touched }"
```

As you can see there is already alot of code already in the above line. I have to use this directive 6 times so my only option as it seems right now is to copy paste it 5 other places. I tried doing something like this but it did not work

```
<form ng-init="formGroupClassObject = { 'has-error' : registerForm.username.$invalid && registerForm.username.$touched, 'has-success' : registerForm.username.$valid && registerForm.username.$touched }">

<div class="form-group" ng-class="formGroupClassObject"></div>
```

I don't understand why this do not work. Do you have any other suggestions on reuse-ability of the code above?

Comment: Why not make your own directive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
ng-class="getFormClasses(registerForm)"
```

And in your common controller:

```
$scope.getFormClasses = function(form) {
  if (!form) { return; }
  return {
    'has-error'  : form.username.$invalid && form.username.$touched,
    'has-success': form.username.$valid   && form.username.$touched
  }
};
```

If you use `ng-init`, the classes will not be updated when the form validity changes.

Comment: That is good suggestion, also I have to change the username to email and password and so on, so a function is a good idea and thanks about the init, I did not know!

Comment: Yep, only add logic in the HTML if it's trivial, otherwise a function is better (even regarding performances)

Comment: how do you pass in the form?

Comment: I get an error TypeError: Cannot read property '$invalid' of undefined

Comment: Did you pass `registerForm` into the function? You can check that `form.username` exists by replacing the first line with `if (!form || !form.username) { return; }` (but I would suggest to `console.log(form)` at the beginning of the function to have an idea what you are manipulating)

Comment: console.log(form) works but not console.log(form.inputName) or console.log(form[inputName]). I pass in the values like this ng-class="getFormControlClassObject(registerForm,username)" where username is the name of the input field. like <input name="username" ...>

Comment: I'm taking in the paramters like this $scope.getFormControlClassObject = function (form, inputName) { ... };

Comment: Hmm. So `console.log(inputName)` and if you see something that matches `form` you should indeed use `form[inputName]`. What exactly does console.log(form) show you? What what inputName are you trying to pass? To pass a parameter in angular js it needs to be in the scope